# Using functions from a different class Visual Studio c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a project in VS C# where it needs to be possible to write to my program true command line and get feedback.
I making this in my Program.cs but I need to be able to use functions made in my Form1.cs. 
The namespace name of my Form1.cs is USBDemoBoard, I already wrote using USBDemoBoard in my Program.cs but he doesn't recognize my function made in Form1.cs

Anyone who can help me? I'm getting really desperate not finding the solution...

The code is in the picture below.

Big thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Hi, you might want to have a read of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Don't post your code as a image. Copy only the portions that are pertinent to the question and format them as code within your question.

Comment: tip - If you need to us functions in more than one place, create a separate class containing those functions

Comment: You should move you methods into it's own class rather than in the Form then instantiate that class whereever you want to use it.

Comment: The image is also to show the errors and the structure of my project.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557)

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to move the `Logic` class to a [Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3cye135(v=vs.80).aspx) and use the Class Library in the Forms and the Console App.

You need, however, [create an Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173110.aspx) from the class using the [new](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4.aspx) keyword , unless you are using a [static class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You have to instantiate your class first. Have a look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)

```
var logic = new Logic();
ok = logic.attemptUSBConnectionFrontEnd_succes()
```

This is really basic knowledge. You should read some tutorials or/and books.

And for the next time: don't put your code as an image; use the *Code sample* tags.

//edit **Namespace**

You have to make the namespace available as well. In you sample you have a lot of `using xxx;`. You have to add a using for the namespace from your Logic class as well. For example the namespace of you sample is USBDemoBoard.

Comment: Thank you for your response. but unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you be more presice? Why does it not work. Maybe it would help when you show us your Logic class.

Comment: @Pierre This answer is correct - how did you try this, and what was the result?

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit a noob whit c#, this is my first time programming in c#.
The error is "The type or namespace 'Logic' could not be found' But the name of my namespace of Form1.cs is USBDemoBoard
if I try it like this it says 'USBDemoBoard' is a namespace but is used like a type
var logic = new USBDemoBoard();
ok = logic.attemptUSBConnectionFrontEnd_succes()

Comment: I edited my post. have a look at the namespace section.

Comment: @Pierre you can't do `new` on a namespace.

Comment: Can't help you anymore without knowing you Logic class.

Comment: ok thank you everyone, it is working

Comment: Your welcome, would be nice up you upvote my answer when it was helping you and accepting it.